# How to share RAM memory with Graphic Memory

Tags: windows-8, memory, graphics-card

My specs :-
1) Dell inspiron 15 3542

2) Video/Graphic memory is not dedicated

3) 4 GB RAM

4) Windows 8 Pro.

I want to share my RAM memory with video/graphic memory..
Mean, I want to use 3 GB of RAM and dedicate 1GB(remaining) to Graphic/Video memory..
Is this possible?
If yes, then how?
any help will be Highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your system should already manage this on its own (see GPU properties in dxdiag). If you have integrated graphics you may be able to increase the maximum VRAM usage in the BIOS (on my ASUS P8Z77-V there is an option to set it to everything from 8M to 1G).

Comment: If you can tell me how to increase max. VRAM, it will be very helpful..Thanks

Comment: Well, there is no precise answer, as it varies between manufacturer and product. It's usually in the `Advanced` tab behind `iGPU settings`.